# Can an accidental vote be changed?

Tags: support, voting, votes

I got a notification that I had a -1 reputation change, and when I checked what caused it, I found that it shows I down-voted [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691489/am-receiver-circuit-problems-with-saturation/691491#691491). I didn't vote on it though; I must have accidentally hit the button while scrolling on my phone, and now it won't let me change it (it says the vote is locked). Can this be corrected so the user doesn't get an undeserved down-vote?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an accidental vote can be changed if the post has been edited since you last voted.  Refer to the following Stack Exchange FAQ:

[What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

Search for the "Limits on changing votes" section:

> you may remove your vote after every time the post is edited
> (excluding grace period edits).

Answer (score -5):

You can try clicking on the button again or upvote. If it doesn't change then there isn't a way to change it. SE doesn't allow anyone to change votes of questions.

Comment: Got it fixed. Apparently the lock is removed if the answer is edited so I just added a few words, undid the vote and then undid the edit.